# Highlight Imageview area according to Coordinate Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, graphics

I have one image in Image view. I want highlight image view area highlight on touchlistener
according to coordinate `(x1,y1)` and  `(x2,y2)`.

I want like this output.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sharedapk.com](https://www.sharedapk.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Ayat-Holy-Quran-1.5.2.jpg))</sub>

this is image and highlight arabic ayat.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could add a 2nd ImageView with same size as your first one above your first one (FrameLayout or RelativeLayout). The 2nd ImageView will contain the highlighter. You can use paddingTop, paddingLeft, paddingRight and paddingBottom to adjust your highlighter.

Some pseudo sample code:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content/>
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/highlighter
        android:src="#500000ff
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Then in your activity:

```
private void drawHighlighter(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    View imgHighlighter = findViewById(R.id.highlighter);
    imgHighlighter.setPadding(x1, y1, imgHighlighter.getWidth() - x2, imgHighlighter.getHeight() - y2);
    imgHighlighter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your.please share some use full tutorial link.how we get required result.

Comment: Christopher! i have approximately 600 copies of images.if i highlight images again one image that is more space.it is very hard work.Can have u any other solution please share.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some more information or some of your current code, as your goal is not clear to me, currently. You could set the needed x1, y1, x2, y2 coordinates to configure the higlighted section.

Comment: Actually i want make like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sa.edu.ksu.Ayat&hl=en app.they use images and stores image coordinate against one image.but i do'nt understand how they highlight image ayat by ayat.i try to implement this requirment.please tell how we implement this logic.i am new in android development.share use full link or code sample.thanks.

Comment: can we draw transparent layer on image according point.I have used static image that store drawable folder.